# No qmake.exe found for Qt Creator 3.2.0

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

So i need to install Qt Creator 3.2.0 and build a project. But, when i try to open the project right now, it is saying "Could not find qmake configuration file default".

Here is my version info:

Qt Creator 3.2.0

Based on Qt 5.3.1

Built on Aug18 2014

I would post pictures of this but i dont have enough rep...

Under kits it says:

Manual - Desktop(default)

Debugger: System GDB at C:\mingw32\bin\gdb.exe

**Qt version: None**

When i try to search for the Qt Version in the Qt folder, the qmake.exe file is nowhere to be found. And i believe this is my issue.

So does anyone know why this .exe is not there or how i can go get it?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you install Qt Creator only? Don't you have a Qt installation?

Comment: @LahiruChandima For what im working on, i was told to install Qt creator 3.2.0. This is the installer i used: qt-creator-opensource-windows-x86-3.2.0. It looks like it only installed Qt creator and nothing else.

I installed Qt v5.4.2 just now and pointed 3.2.0 to the location of the new qmake.exe.
But that didnt help because now i get the message "All setting files found in directory are either too new or too old to be read"

Comment: You can't do much with Qt Creator alone. To successfully compile a Qt application with Qt Creator, you need a Qt library installation. qmake.exe comes with the Qt library installation, not with Qt Creator.

Comment: @LahiruChandima I just ran a Qt 5.4.2 library installation. But, When i open the Qt project file, it says parsing c++ files, etc, and gives no errors. But none of the c++ or header files open when it is finished. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: What do you mean with, they don't open? On the very left bar, click on the second Option "Edit", then in the menubar Window->"Show Sidebar", then in the appearing sidebar, select "Projects" if it is not already selected. Now you should see your project structure.

Answer (score 3):

Qt Creator alone is not enough.

You must install Qt SDK with the source file.

Go there and take the open source version : https://www.qt.io/download/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the online installer, then select the sdk version and the tools.
In my case its on the `C:\Qt\6.6.2\mingw_64\bin` directory.

[image: QT ONline manager]